# SSL/urllib error while running code on kaggle-editor

Tags: python, urllib, kaggle

link to specific notebook :- https://www.kaggle.com/code/hamedghorbani/plant-disease-classification-fine-tuned-99-3

```
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
```

error occured in this part of the code

```
# Load the pretained model
pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB5(
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    include_top=False, # we don`t need a pre-trained top layer (output layer)
    weights='imagenet',
    pooling='max'
)

# Freezing the layers of a pretrained neural network
for i, layer in enumerate(pretrained_model.layers):
    pretrained_model.layers[i].trainable = False
```

these are the firsrt two lines of the error, complete error is given below :-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1282, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1281 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1282 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1328, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1327     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1328 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1277, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1276     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1277 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1037, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1036 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1037 self.send(msg)
   1039 if message_body is not None:
   1040 
   1041     # create a consistent interface to message_body

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:975, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
    974 if self.auto_open:
--> 975     self.connect()
    976 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:1447, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
   1445 "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."
-> 1447 super().connect()
   1449 if self._tunnel_host:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/http/client.py:941, in HTTPConnection.connect(self)
    940 sys.audit("http.client.connect", self, self.host, self.port)
--> 941 self.sock = self._create_connection(
    942     (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    943 # Might fail in OSs that don't implement TCP_NODELAY

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/socket.py:824, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    823 err = None
--> 824 for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    825     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/socket.py:955, in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    954 addrlist = []
--> 955 for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    956     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:346, in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir, hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
    345 try:
--> 346     urlretrieve(origin, fpath, DLProgbar())
    347 except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:85, in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
     83             break
---> 85 response = urlopen(url, data)
     86 with open(filename, "wb") as fd:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:216, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    215     opener = _opener
--> 216 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:519, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    518 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 519 response = self._open(req, data)
    521 # post-process response

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:536, in OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)
    535 protocol = req.type
--> 536 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    537                           '_open', req)
    538 if result:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:496, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    495 func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 496 result = func(*args)
    497 if result is not None:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1391, in HTTPSHandler.https_open(self, req)
   1390 def https_open(self, req):
-> 1391     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
   1392         context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/urllib/request.py:1351, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1351     raise URLError(err)
   1352 r = h.getresponse()

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 2
      1 # Load the pretained model
----> 2 pretrained_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB5(
      3     input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
      4     include_top=False, # we don`t need a pre-trained top layer (output layer)
      5     weights='imagenet',
      6     pooling='max'
      7 )
      9 # Freezing the layers of a pretrained neural network
     10 for i, layer in enumerate(pretrained_model.layers):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/efficientnet.py:753, in EfficientNetB5(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, classifier_activation, **kwargs)
    739 @keras_export(
    740     "keras.applications.efficientnet.EfficientNetB5",
    741     "keras.applications.EfficientNetB5",
   (...)
    751     **kwargs,
    752 ):
--> 753     return EfficientNet(
    754         1.6,
    755         2.2,
    756         456,
    757         0.4,
    758         model_name="efficientnetb5",
    759         include_top=include_top,
    760         weights=weights,
    761         input_tensor=input_tensor,
    762         input_shape=input_shape,
    763         pooling=pooling,
    764         classes=classes,
    765         classifier_activation=classifier_activation,
    766         **kwargs,
    767     )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/applications/efficientnet.py:457, in EfficientNet(width_coefficient, depth_coefficient, default_size, dropout_rate, drop_connect_rate, depth_divisor, activation, blocks_args, model_name, include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, classifier_activation)
    455         file_hash = WEIGHTS_HASHES[model_name[-2:]][1]
    456     file_name = model_name + file_suffix
--> 457     weights_path = data_utils.get_file(
    458         file_name,
    459         BASE_WEIGHTS_PATH + file_name,
    460         cache_subdir="models",
    461         file_hash=file_hash,
    462     )
    463     model.load_weights(weights_path)
    464 elif weights is not None:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py:350, in get_file(fname, origin, untar, md5_hash, file_hash, cache_subdir, hash_algorithm, extract, archive_format, cache_dir)
    348         raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.code, e.msg))
    349     except urllib.error.URLError as e:
--> 350         raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
    351 except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
    352     if os.path.exists(fpath):

Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/keras-applications/efficientnetb5_notop.h5: None -- [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

I was running multiple notebooks to make a model on kaggle about plant diseases but all the notebooks were showing the same error.

Comment: The bottom of your trace is `Exception: URL fetch failure on https://storage.googleapis.com/keras-applications/efficientnetb5_notop.h5: None -- [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`, my understanding of this is possibly a network or DNS issue when retrieving data for your models locally, but it's hard to say definitively. Have you read SO's "minimal reproducible example"? It might help focus discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example